# Unexplained errors due to fopen() and FILE

Tags: c, file, fopen, stdio

I can't understand the errors that crop up due to the following code.I am trying to open a file using `fopen()`, but the errors make no sense to me.So please explain the whole thing.

```
10 - FILE * THE_FILE_YOU_READ;
11 - THE_FILE_YOU_READ = fopen("num.txt","r");
```

These two line alone produces several warnings and errors,as follows:

```
11 - warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
11 - error: conflicting types for 'THE_FILE_YOU_READ'
10 - note: previous declaration of 'THE_FILE_YOU_READ' was here
11 - warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
11 - error: initializer element is not constant
```

I'm using  Code::Blocks if it's relevant at all. I have not declared this variable `THE_FILE_YOU_READ anywhere else in the program. Any ideas, or is this simply a stupid oversight on my part?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've written this code outside of any function, at the file scope. That's invalid. Statements can only occur in functions. Outside of a function, the compiler is trying to interpret the second line as a declaration/definition, with an implicit type of `int`.

Comment: @R You are absolutely right.I didn't see the OP telling that he is sure he didn't declare that anywhere before.But the question was so clumsy I missed it.Thanks for the insight.I am deleting my answer as my premise was wrong.

Comment: OP didn't say that; I deduced it from the fact that the compiler was interpreting line 11 that way, which would not happen at function level.

Comment: What does line 11 mean?`Initializer element not constant` What that means?

Comment: If it's interpreting the right-hand side of the equals sign as an initializer, that means it's interpreting the left-hand side as a declaration/definition for an object. In a statement context, the equals sign would be an operator, not part of an initializer construct.

Comment: By the way, I would say this is a reason it's harmful for the compiler to keep supporting (by default) deprecated K&R constructs that were removed from the language decades ago. If it weren't for this obscure implicit-int declaration rule, the compiler could have given a more-informative error message indicating that it encountered a statement outside a function.

Comment: Yeah, I got that,but then what with the `not constant` part?What does `not constant` mean?Plz tell.

Comment: Since the object is "declared" (albeit unintentionally) at file scope, it has static storage duration. Initializers for objects of static storage duration must be constant expressions. The result of a function call is not a constant expression.

Comment: Got it.But you give me an inferiority complex.How many years of experience with C you have?

Comment: Can you tell me how come objects declared at file scope have **static** storage duration?I mean, aren't they **extern** by default?I am sure both keywords achieve the same purpose in this context,but why didn't you use the word **extern** and said **static storage**?

Comment: Because it's the storage duration, not the linkage, that matters. All objects at file scope have static storage duration (which means their lifetime is the entire duration of the program execution).